# How do I SSH into gcloud compute instance as ubuntu user?

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, ssh-keys

We have a VM Instance in Google Cloud that is being used by two user. We want to create another user the can be accessible by both. We chose the user `ubuntu` for that like in AWS. But the problem is we can login when running the following command.
`gcloud compute --project "project" ssh --zone "us-east1-b" "gpunew3"`

It's showing the following error.

`ubuntu@35.196.254.72: Permission denied (publickey).
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].`

What can be the possible way to achieve this.

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect a key pair mismatch. Please run the follow command to remove the private key file:

## rm .ssh/google_compute_engine

Then run your command to ssh again, which will recreate a new key pair.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem before,and i fixed it by adding my public key in VM Instance and then  connect to VM Instance by ssh like this

```
ssh VM External IP
```

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys